# Show that f is not an increasing function on any neighbourhood of 0.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, monotone-functions

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as 
>   $$
> f(x)= \begin{cases} x, & x \in \mathbb{Q}\\ x−x^2, & x \not \in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}
> $$
>   Show that $f$ is not an increasing function on any neighbourhood of $0$.

Please help I have no idea how to even start this proof!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that if $x \in (0,\epsilon)$, then $x^2>0$ and $x^2<x$. Therefore, $x-x^2 < x$, so you only have to find a rational $x$ and a slightly larger irrational $x+\delta$.

Comment: So there is 2 cases , (-,0) and (0,). To find this x is there an -N proof that needs to be followed

Comment: @agirlbadatmath yes, there are 2 cases in the complete argument.